# How to config postfix in Zimbra

Tags: postfix-mta, zimbra, zimlet

I am developing a content filtering app for zimbra. I have a problem with the config postfix MTA.

In main.cf

```
 content-filter:smpt-amavis[127.0.0.1]:1024 by content-filter:myfilter
```

and add `master.cf` myfilter service to pipe email to script php.

But when I restart zimbra, everything returns to default,

```
 content-filter:smtp-amavis
```

How my config change when I restart zimbra. Could anyone help me, please. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

did you check the master.cf.in ???

https://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/Adding_additional_SMTP_listener_ports

You must edit the master.cf.in because this is the file readed by zimbra to update the config file (master.cf).  If you try to edit directly the master.cf, when restart de service the changes will be erased (because he read the master.cf.in to update changes)

Comment: thank you.i have changed it.I want to redirect all incoming email to my script.I have followed http://www.postfix.org/FILTER_README.html
But it seem not right, postfix  can't perform my php script.i need configure anythingelse ???

Comment: i recommend you test your script only with a pure postfix.  Finally the zimbra engine is postfix, so you must discard if your script work correctly just with postfix.